# Progress bar doesn't update

Tags: android, progress-bar

I created a Progress bar but I can't see the loading animation. It's frozen. I want to display a progress bar when I click on the item and then see the bar working and not frozen. Here is my code:

```
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
           if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("Zman-New (rus)")){

               progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(testLoading.this, "Getting data", "Loading...",true,true);
               new GetDataTask("stringurl.xml").execute();

              }
```

Here is the getdata

```
 private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
String url;
GetDataTask(String url){
    this.url=url;
}
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do all your backgroundtasks 
      intent = new Intent(rusNewsP.testLoading.this, rusNewsTest.rusNewsActivite.class);
      intent.putExtra("url",url);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
        return 1;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        //finish up ( or close the progressbar )

        //do something with the result
    progDailog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test Progress try this:

```
private class Initialize extends AsyncTask<Short, Short, Short> {
            ProgressDialog pd;



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(yourlass.this);
    pd.setMessage("test");
    pd.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Short doInBackground(Short... params) {
    try {
    synchronized (this) {
        wait(2000);
    }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Short result) {
    pd.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

And don't call `startActivity` in the `doInBackground`-Method. Call it in OnPostExecute instead. GUI Operations should not be done in doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **start** the `Activity` **Direct** from the **UI thread** as that will be fast.
Still,if you want this way then try to start it from the **onPostExecute Method**.
Not from the **doInBackground**.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
{
    //do something with the result
  progDailog.dismiss();
  intent=new Intent(rusNewsP.testLoading.this,rusNewsTest.rusNewsActivite.class);
  intent.putExtra("url",url);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

And...**don't call** `super.onPostExecute(result);` after **dismissing** the **progressDialog**..after completing the `doInBackground(Short... params)`,It will return directly to **onPostExecute** Method where it will dismiss the `ProgressDialog` first time and then execute the **Constructor** which will try again to dismiss the `ProgressDialog` which is already **dismissed** resulting into uncaught exception.